# How to clear the credentials used by TeamsFx SSO?

Tags: microsoft-teams, teams-toolkit

i've got multiple microsoft accounts linked to multiple tenants. I've registered my first teams app (using the Office Toolkit functionality "Configure for SSO...") on the wrong tenant.
Is there some way to remove the stored credentials? I even tried making a new solution, but visual studio seems to have stored those credentials somewhere, just can't find where.

Answer (score 1):

I am the engineer of VS extension of Teams Toolkit. We have identified this requirement from GitHub issue https://github.com/OfficeDev/TeamsFx/issues/1685, and will treat it as a new feature in the following release. So far, you can follow the workaround in that GitHub issue thread and thanks for your patience.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Answer (score 0):

Only solution I could find.

- Open Visual studio and go to Extensions -> Manage Extensions
- Uninstall Teams toolkit
- Install toolkit again
- It should allow you to sign in again when you configure SSO

Comment: I tried this and then found that I couldn't find the toolkit for installation in Extensions to reinstall it. (VS 2022).  I then tried through the Visual Studio installer to add the Microsoft Teams Development tools workload, but when I tried to update VS, it didn't install the Teams tools.  I ended up having to uninstall and reinstall ASP.Net and web development (making sure to tick MS Teams Dev Tools).  This got me back going again, but did not fix the credential problem.  Good way to burn an hour!